Issue with getting Jar dependencies via Jdeps
I want to create a JLink image of a jar file of my Java project and I'm using Maven as build tool. I'm trying to get all dependencies needed to run my project to create a JLink image of it by using the command:
jdeps --print-module-deps -cp <classpath> -R --multi-release 17 <jar path>

where I get jar's classpath via the command:
mvn dependency:build-classpath

While I expect to get a list of all dependencies I need to include to my JRE image, I only get a huge list of warnings of the form:
Warning: split package: <package name> <jar address> <package address>

I'm also using a number of third-party libraries and I'm on openJDK-18. What should I do to prevent this error?
I'd be really grateful for any workaround to the problem I'm facing and/or any idea of its cause

Have you considered running JPackage? It runs JLink internally.

@queeg unfortunately I'm not familiar with it. Could you explain a little bit?

Here is some nice documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-overview.html
If you do not like complete packaging, use --type app-image

Besides all the warnings, is there any other output?

@JornVernee No. All lines of output are warnings

Do the split packages always come from the same groups of dependencies? Also, is the image generated as it should be (apart from the warnings)?

I don't get what you mean by "group of dependencies". Also if I get what you're saying correctly, I don't get any dependency to put in thd console command to get a JRE image ans test it.

I suspect you have modularized jars in <jar path> that contain the same package names. It should be OK to ignore these warnings, but if you really want to get rid of them (and I assume you don't want to grep -v them), you will have to dive deeper into these jars, i.e. unpacking them and finding the ones with the corresponding packages, and then trying to see if you really need one or the other.
